# Mongoose invalidate in pre validate hook does not throw error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async-await, mongoose-schema

I have the following pre validate hook in my user model :

```
UserSchema.pre<IUser>('validate', async function (next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
    if (!this.isModified('password')) {
        return next()
    }
    if (this.password.length < 8) {
        this.invalidate(
            'password',
            'Invalid password ...',
            ''
        )
        console.log(this.password)
    }
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12)
})
```

The schema is :

```
const UserSchema: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    login: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        unique: 'Le nom d\'utilisateur `{VALUE}` est déjà utilisé'
    },
    mail: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        unique: 'Le mail `{VALUE}` est déjà utilisé'
    },
    password: { required: true, type: String, /*select: false*/ },
    // In test env auto validate users
    isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: config.env !== 'test' ? false : true },
    profilPic: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Image' },
}, { timestamps: true })
```

However when doing

```
try {
   await User.create({ login: 'user2', mail: 'user1@mail.com', password: '123' })
} catch (error) {
   console.log(error)
}
```

I have the log `123` which indicate that the code enters in the second `if` in the pre hook but since the log is after the `this.invalidate` I don't understand why there is no error thrown.

I successfully used the same hook in some other models with more complexes operations without error.

I really fail to grasp why this one is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background of such behavior is that `Document.prototype.invalidate()` does not **throws** an error - it **returns** an error. In order to stop the current middleware chain from execution, you need to either call `next` and pass it this error:

```
if (this.password.length < 8) {
    const validationError = this.invalidate(
        'password',
        'Invalid password ...',
        ''
    );
    next(validationError);
    console.log(this.password); // Won't run
}
```

or `throw` it:

```
if (this.password.length < 8) {
    const validationError = this.invalidate(
        'password',
        'Invalid password ...',
        ''
    );
    throw validationError;
    console.log(this.password); // Won't run
}
```

Comment: I used the exact same function in an other model without explicit `return` nor `throw` but that might be on my side

Comment: The way `Document.prototype.invalidate()` works is that it adds an error to the error map of document instance and returns it. Running `Document.prototype.validate()` right after invalidation will pass an object with `errors` field and some metadata as an argument of the callback of `validate()`. You can check it in [docs with an example](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-invalidate). Maybe you haven't notices that `invalidate()` does not throws but returns an error because there was nothing more to execute.

Comment: Try to `console.log` of the value returned by `this.invalidate()` and you will see it

Comment: Sorry, was a little tired yesterday and failed to see that I had `return next()` in my other model. Both of your solutions works, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose [middleware documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) does not list create as a supported operation. Did you try with save?

Comment: I might have missed something, but looking at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html `create` is clearly a supported mongoose operation.

Comment: Create is definitely a supported operation... just that it is not mentioned under the list supported operations for middleware.